# Visual Studio Express SOAP functions limited?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, zend-framework, soap

I have a SOAP endpoint implemented in Zend Framework.

When I create a C# project with Visual Studio Professional 2008, add a web service reference and use the service, it works like a charm. I can also import the project into Visual Studion Express (C#) 2008 and Visual Studio Express Desktop 2012. Those work too.

If i create the same project in one of the express versions of Visual Studio, they will throw a SoapHeaderException. Same settings and everything.

Apparently the projects created with an Express version of VS can only use Webservices that send primitives and one-dimensional arrays.

WSDL.exe runs through without errors or warnings.

Anybody experienced these problems before?

Comment: Simply put both solution folders next to each other and make a diff to see the differences. Maybe it's a bug?